# Alchemy's AS3_Shim broken?

Tags: flash, alchemy

I'm trying to use [AS3_Shim](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Alchemy:Documentation:Developing_with_Alchemy:C_API#void_.2AAS3_Shim.28AS3_Val_func.2C_AS3_Val_thiz.2C_const_char_.2Art.2C_const_char_.2Att.2C__int_varargs.29) in my alchemy code but it doesn't seem to be working.  It always returns a NULL function pointer.  There don't seem to be any examples of AS3_Shim's use, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Here is some example code:

```
static AS3_Val thunk_logtest(void *self, AS3_Val args) {

    // warning: this leaks
    AS3_Val ns= AS3_String("mx.logging");
    AS3_Val clazz= AS3_NSGetS(ns, "Log");
    AS3_Val logger= AS3_CallTS("getLogger", clazz, "StrType", "alchemy");

    // works
    AS3_Val logret= AS3_CallTS("debug", logger, "StrType", "this is a test");

    // doesn't work: AS3_Shim returns NULL!
    typedef void (*log_func_t)(const char[], ...);   
    log_func_t log_func= (log_func_t)AS3_Shim(AS3_String("debug"), logger, "VoidType", "StrType", true);
    printf("log_func= %d \n", log_func); fflush(stdout);

    // because log_func is NULL, this throws TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function
    log_func("this is a test");

    return AS3_Undefined();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AS3_Shim` expects a function for its first parameter, not a function name.  Replace `AS3_String("debug")` with `AS3_GetS(logger, "debug")`

```
log_func_t log_func = (log_func_t)AS3_Shim(
    AS3_GetS(logger, "debug"), logger, "VoidType", "StrType", true );
```

Comment: OHHhhhh...  It was highly unclear from the docs what they meant.  I didn't realize you could use AS3_Get to get a function (I thought it was just for properties).  Thanks!

Comment: @paleo: You can also use it to access Array elements by sending the desired index as a String.